# SSH brute-force from my network / domain

Tags: ssh, brute-force-attacks

Twice a week I receive an email to abuse@mydomain.tld that says:

```
An attempt to brute-force account passwords over SSH/FTP by a machine in your domain or in your network has been detected. Attached are the host who attacks and time / date of activity. Please take the necessary action(s) to stop this activity immediately. If you have any questions please reply to this email.

Host of attacker: <MYIP> => server.mydomain.tld => mydomain.tld
Responsible email contacts: abuse@mydomain.tld, abuse@ovh.net
Attacked hosts in our Network: 37.228.155.101, 185.39.222.116, 77.75.254.116, 185.39.221.179, 37.228.154.167, 37.228.154.61, 85.158.181.17, 185.39.222.20

Logfile entries (time is MET / GMT+1):
Sat Jun 22 06:51:55 2019: user: vnc service: ssh target: 185.39.221.179 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:48:29 2019: user: mysqldump service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:46:59 2019: user: testftp service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:45:59 2019: user: www-data service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:44:29 2019: user: ubuntu service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:43:29 2019: user: postgres service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:41:59 2019: user: ubuntu service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:40:59 2019: user: dong service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
Sat Jun 22 06:39:29 2019: user: root service: ssh target: 185.39.222.116 source: <MYIP>
[ ... other 4 IPs ... ]
```

They are always the same 4 IPs.
For SSH authentication I use Google 2 factor, I have root user disabled and only an user allowed. I have also changed che port.
This is a VPS by OVH where I have a mail server so I'm a little worried.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How can I prevent SSH brute-force over my network?

Comment: This is not a brute-force attack against your server but **from** your server. If you don't react and fix this problem, they won't stay so kind and just notice you. Once OVH gets these abuse reports, they'll probably unplug your VPS.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to solve

Comment: Read the linked canonical question about compromised hosts. Find out who is on your system and what they are doing. The abuse mail tells you when this happened.